# Какой смысл от использования объектов в качестве ключа?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Открыл [исходник](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridView.cs,f39ee7c8c540fdec) одного из компонента WinForms и увидел это:

```
  private static readonly object EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWALLOWUSERTOADDROWSCHANGED = new object();
    private static readonly object EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWALLOWUSERTODELETEROWSCHANGED = new object();
    private static readonly object EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWALLOWUSERTOORDERCOLUMNSCHANGED = new object();
    private static readonly object EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWALLOWUSERTORESIZECOLUMNSCHANGED = new object();
    private static readonly object EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWALLOWUSERTORESIZEROWSCHANGED = new object();
    private static readonly object EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWALTERNATINGROWSDEFAULTCELLSTYLECHANGED = new object();
    private static readonly object EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWAUTOGENERATECOLUMNSCHANGED = new object();
    private static readonly object EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWAUTOSIZECOLUMNMODECHANGED = new object();
    private static readonly object EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWAUTOSIZECOLUMNSMODECHANGED = new object();
    private static readonly object EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWAUTOSIZEROWSMODECHANGED = new object();
    private static readonly object EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWBACKGROUNDCOLORCHANGED = new object();
    private static readonly object EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWBORDERSTYLECHANGED = new object();
    private static readonly object EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWCANCELROWEDIT = new object();
    private static readonly object EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWCELLBEGINEDIT = new object();
    private static readonly object EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWCELLBORDERSTYLECHANGED = new object();
    private static readonly object EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWCELLCLICK = new object();
    private static readonly object EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWCELLCONTENTCLICK = new object();
```

Далее видно, что это все используется в качестве ключа в словаре.

Я знаю, что в рамках потока создаваемый объект получает уникальный идентификатор, но разве не проще ли было enum сделать? Какой-либо смысл был, если бы словарь был глобальным, но он создается отдельно на каждый компонент.

Comment: Никакого смысла. Проще хранить числа или перечисления как ключи.

Comment: только вот они не используются как ключи в словаре, если приглядеться, то увидите, что там не словарь, а связанный список.

Comment: в связвнном списке они не используют сравнение по хешу, они сравнивают сами объекты, принимая `object` как идентификатор.

Comment: Дело может быть в том, что этот код писался в первой версии фреймворка, когда ещё не было дженериков и т. п. Это могло накладывать отпечаток на образ мышления в целом при разработке.

Comment: @tym32167 не проще, если над кодом одновременно работают несколько людей (или даже команд). в числах - конфликты, enum - придется или вручную нумеровать, или значения поедут. а так - скопипастил строчку и готово.

Comment: @PashaPash там ниже в том же файле есть айдишники - числа, пронумерованные вручную :)

Comment: @tym32167 там не ID, там флаги :)